# What is Nyaya's view on devatās?

Tags: gods, nyaya, devatas

Nyaya is a school of philosophy in Hinduism.

It is a theistic school which believes in one supreme God.

So do nyaya school believe in devatās and do they consider worshipping them.

Or do they reject the existence of devatās.

Comment: The theology of Nyâya and Vaiśheśhika is such that, corporeal divinities aren't much needed.